# In Dockerfile build how to get container with ssh keys loaded in

Tags: docker, ssh

I have docker image which already have keys saved.I want to get docker container which will have ssh keys loaded when i run it. I went over few stackoverflow questions where its suggested to use as below which didnt help

RUN  eval $(ssh-agent -s) && ssh-add /root/.ssh/ok

My Dockerfile look like

FROM cmf

RUN  eval $(ssh-agent -s) && ssh-add /root/.ssh/ok

when i created docker image and ran it like , i dont see keys loaded

> docker run -it intro_to_docker2 /bin/bash

root@17a094f42efb:/# ssh-add -l

Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
root@17a094f42efb:/#

Below is build

% docker build --no-cache -t intro_to_docker2 .
[+] Building 0.3s (6/6) FINISHED
=> [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                               0.0s
=> => transferring dockerfile: 102B                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
=> [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
=> => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
=> [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/cmf:latest                                                                                                                                      0.0s
=> CACHED [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/cmf                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
=> [2/2] RUN  eval $(ssh-agent -s) && ssh-add /root/.ssh/ok                                                                                                                                       0.2s
=> exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
=> => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
=> => writing image sha256:4acb58d65b43a15e6a85a99f99d223d87c90736eed07d427e8ceaeac544f87a4                                                                                                       0.0s
=> => naming to docker.io/library/intro_to_docker2

Comment: RUN is done during _build_ but only _files_ are saved in the image (plus metadata like networking), not processes so that doesn't work. To have the container when created/run include a _process_ it must be started (and initialized) either by the un-overridden  CMD or the ENTRYPOINT. This can be explicit, or if your image runs a shell it could be in the startup for that shell which involves files you can put in the image in the same way as other files e.g. .bashrc for bash, .zshrc for zsh

Comment: Note that anyone who has a Docker image can pretty trivially extract files from it; if the image includes ssh keys or other credentials you should probably consider them compromised.